# Events on a navbar component

Tags: angular, typescript

At the main template on app.component I have this :

```
<bs-navbar></bs-navbar>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I need make some decisions to initialize the navbar displaying or not some options depending the customer rights that I save on login. I can read these options from a service. My problem is how can I use events like ngOnInit on the navbar component. As I can see, events like ngOnInit on navbar are not fired.

At the navbar component I have :

```
import { GlobalsService } from './../globals.service';
import { any } from 'codelyzer/util/function';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export enum userProfile {
    Admin = 1 ,
    Normal = 2
}

@Component({
   selector: 'bs-navbar',
   templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})


export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

UserProfile ;

constructor(private router: Router, public globals: GlobalsService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.UserProfile = this.globals.getValueParaTipoDeOperador ;
    console.log('User profile -> ', this.UserProfile );
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do I understand you correctly..  You have user permission stored in local storage, and you need a way to access it and then display data depending on those permissions?

Comment: I'm using a service to store the permissions after login. And, yes , with these permissions some options at the navbar will or not be displayed.

Comment: Okey. What exactly is the problem?
Do you have problems accessing the data in your `*.component.ts` file ? 
or, Is it something else ?

Comment: I need fire an event on the navbar component like ngOnInit but the event is not fired

Comment: Could you provide code from your `...ts file`

Comment: Shure, the ts is now on the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156961/discussion-between-andresson-and-gcoe).

Comment: Thank you but now I'm must leave

Comment: One way I handle my events on my navbar is when the drop downs close and open.